# Count NAs in vector except at the beginning

Tags: r

How to count NAs ignoring beginning NAs?

```
temp <- c(NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA, 56, NA)
```

Total number of NAs in this vector is 5 and beginning NA sequence contains two elements. Hence, the correct answer should be 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can subset the `vector` from the first non-NA element and then do the `is.na` to get a logical vector and get the `sum`

```
sum(is.na(temp[which(!is.na(temp))[1]:length(temp)]))
#[1] 3
```

Or another option is to subset based on the `cumsum` of logical vector and then do as above

```
sum(is.na(temp[cumsum(!is.na(temp))>0]))
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with `rle`:

```
with(rle(is.na(temp)), sum(lengths[-1][values[-1]]))
#[1] 3
```

This means we first compute the run lengths of each NA / non-NA sequence. Then we sum up all the lengths of the NA-sequences but we exclude the first sequence. The first sequence can be an NA-sequence, in which case we want to exclude it. It could also be a non-NA sequence but in this case we don't mind if it's removed since we only want to sum up the NA-sequence lengths.